# Dynamic way to compute linear constraints with multiple operators

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic

Imagine a matrix `A` having one column with a lot of inequality/equality operators (≥, = ≤) and a vector `b`, where the number of rows in `A` is equal the number of elements in `b`. Then one row, in my setting would be computed by, e.g

```
dot(A[0, 1:], x) ≥ b[0]
```

where `x` is some vector, column `A[,0]` represents all operators and we'd know that for row 0 we were suppose to calculate using `≥` operator (e.i. `A[0,0] == "≥"` is true). Now, is there a way for dynamically calculate all rows in following so far imaginary way

```
dot(A[, 1:], x) A[, 0] b
```

My hope was for a dynamic evaluation of each row where we evaluate which operator is used for each row.

Example, let

```
A = [
         [">=", -2, 1, 1],
         [">=",  0, 1, 0],
         ["==",  0, 1, 1]
    ]

b = [0, 1, 1]
```

and x be some given vector, e.g. `x = [1,1,0]` we wish to compute as following

```
       A[,1:]          x       A[,0]     b
dot([-2, 1,  1],   [1, 1, 0])   >=       0
dot([0,  1,  0],   [1, 1, 0])   >=       1
dot([0,  1,  1],   [1, 1, 0])   ==       1
```

The output would be `[False, True, True]`

Comment: Thank you, that's much clearer now. So, is `A` actually a NumPy array, or just a list of lists at the moment? I mean because it contains different types of data. I think I would do the three comparison for all elements and then pick the right result with `np.where` or `np.choose`...

Comment: Yeah so here's where I'm not sure anymore of the data structure. Let say that I did know that all rows where suppose to be computed using e.g. `≥` and all was integer np-arrays, then I'd just do `np.dot(A, x) >= b` and I'd be done. So I'm looking for a way to do that but with the operator varying with the row...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a way to do that operation:

```py
import numpy as np
# Input data
a = [
         [">=", -2, 1, 1],
         [">=",  0, 1, 0],
         ["==",  0, 1, 1]
    ]
b = np.array([0, 1, 1])
x = np.array([1, 1, 0])
# Split in comparison and data
a0 = np.array([lst[0] for lst in a])
a1 = np.array([lst[1:] for lst in a])
# Compute dot product
c = a1 @ x
# Compute comparisons
leq = c <= b
eq = c == b
geq = c >= b
# Find comparison index for each row
cmps = np.array(["<=", "==", ">="])  # This array is lex sorted
cmp_idx = np.searchsorted(cmps, a0)
# Select the right result for each row
result = np.choose(cmp_idx, [leq, eq, geq])
# Convert to numeric type if preferred
result = result.astype(np.int32)
print(result)
# [0 1 1]
```